# Проблема при использовании onTouch и onClick

Tags: android, android-on-click, ontouchlistener, touch-event

Столкнулся с проблемой, при использовании методов `onTouch()` и `onClick()`. Дело в том, что, если эти оба методы определить в одном классе - то `onTouch()` не срабатывает!

```
 public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TaskName> implements  View.OnTouchListener, View.OnClickListener{

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TaskName> taskNames){
        super(context, 0 , taskNames);
        this.context = (MainGridActivity) context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = context.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.grid_view_item, null);
        }
        convertView.setTag(position);

        convertView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

        taskName = getItem(position);
        nameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        nameView.setText(taskName.getTaskName());
        countView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count_task);
        countView.setText(String.valueOf(taskName.getTaskNameId()));


      return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            int pos = Integer.valueOf(view.getTag().toString());
            Log.d(LOG, getItem(pos).getTaskName());
            Log.d(LOG, String.valueOf(getItem(pos).getTaskNameId()));
            selectedItemText = getItem(pos).getTaskName();
            selectedItemId = getItem(pos).getTaskNameId();
        }
        return false;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Это класс адаптера, для GridView!

В фрагменте я устанавливаю  GridView контекстное меню для удаления элемента ! Именно для определения того,который элемент удалять и служит `onTouch()`. В фрагмент передается значение элемента на который совершено касание, соответственно если на нем вызывается контекстное меню для удаления - он удаляется!

Мне нужно совершить переход на другое активити после касания на элемент GridView - от для этого и использую `onClick()`.

**Не могу понять где я натупил и в чем проблема!
 Как мне исправить данную проблему ? 

Это моя первая практика android и может что-то делаю не правильно, приму любую конструктивно критику и совет!! 

Спасибо!!**

Comment: А если возвращать `true` из `onTouch()`?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так делать тоже побывал - ничего не меняется !

Comment: Может в условие не попадает? Попробуйте if убрать...

Comment: ну на первый взгляд нет ошибки c listnerами, нужно смотреть в др месте. Я бы в 1 очередь посмотрел в самой activity, если используется listner-ы могут перекрывать эти и во 2-й убедился что convertView корректно инфлейтится для grid,

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, нет ...даже так не работает !!!

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, convertView  вроде инфлейтится коректно!!! Заметил что после удаления onTouch - работает onClick ,но не вызывается контекстное меню.....только закоментил onClick - контекстное меню вызывается !

Comment: покажите  класс где происходит работа с адаптеров который выше описан, думаю всётаки там ошибка. Здесь явно её нет.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, Спасибо за отклик и потраченное на меня время !!!  Вы дали подсказку насчет возможности не совместимости листнеров! И были правы - заменил grid.setOnClickListener на grid.setOnItemClickListener, это было действительно в в самой activity !!!

Comment: Я рад, что хоть чем-то смог помочь - удачи)

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, спасибо ))))

Answer (score 3):

Для перехода на другое активити используй Intent. Внимательно погугли, почитай о нем документацию и только потом юзай. **Доки гугла твой лучший друг.**

Comment: спасибо - я знаю как это делать ! Но проблема не в том !)))

Comment: ну ладн... джун сумничать пытался

Comment: ахаха...та ничего))) спасибо за отклик )